# Magento 2.3.3 dashboard keeps loading

Tags: admin, magento2, loading, dashboard

I have installed latest version of magento in my localhost.
After login to admin panel dashboard keeps loading.

Here is the image-

[image]
Please help to solve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Go to magento root directory then :

vendor/magento/framework/view/element/tempalate/file/validator.php (dont exactly copy this url just follow this path)

open this file using any editor and change this line

```
 $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path); //you can comment this out
    with this one

$realPath = str_replace('\\','/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
then goto to
```

app/etc/di.xml

and search for view_preprocessed

you will find a whole line like this :

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
and change the **Symlink** with **Copy**

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.3

1. go to *\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File*
2. go to the function *isPathInDirectories* and replace the function with following

   ```
    protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        //$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
        $realPath = str_replace('\\','/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            //$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
            $realDirectory = str_replace('\\','/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory));
            if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
               return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
   ```
3. go to app/etc/di.xml then search for view_preprocessed

you will find a whole line like this :

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink and change to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Answer (score 0):

#1. go to vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php#
#2. go to the function isPathInDirectories and replace the function with following:#

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
 {
     if (!is_array($directories)) {
         $directories = (array)$directories;
     }
     //$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
     $realPath = str_replace('\\','/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
     foreach ($directories as $directory) {
         //$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
         $realDirectory = str_replace('\\','/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory));
         if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
            return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

#3. go to app/etc/di.xml then search for view_preprocessed

you will find a whole line like this :

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink and change to
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy #